# Why is "open in new tab" sending a GET request?

Tags: javascript, html, web, request

I have the following HTML tag

```
<a href="#" id="navBar_navBarInput_3_subNavDropdownInput_0_subNavLinkInput_0" onclick="redirectPost(4,'EntryData.aspx');">My Link</a>
```

The Javascript "redirectPost"

```
function redirectPost(id, url) {
            post(url, { id: id });
        }

function post(path, params, method) {
            method = method || "post";
            var form = document.createElement("form");
            form.setAttribute("method", method);
            form.setAttribute("action", path);

            for (var key in params) {
                if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
                    hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                    hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
                    hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

                    form.appendChild(hiddenField);
                }
            }

            document.body.appendChild(form);
            form.submit();
        }
```

Here's the deal: when I just click on the link, the page sends a regular POST request. But whenever I use "open in a new tab" option, it sends a GET request and this is a problem for me since I do some validations background.

Does anyone have any idea why it behaves this way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Because clicking a link activates the click handler; right-clicking it and choosing "Open in new tab" does not, it just reads the `href` and uses that to open a new tab.

On some browsers, you can override the context menu by hooking the `contextmenu` event and preventing its default action. This doesn't work on all browsers, though.

Fundamentally, if your link isn't really a link but rather is a button, it should be a `button` (or `input type="button"`), not an `a`. You can style those to look how you want them to look. Using the right element will help the browser provide the right options to the user for that element.

Answer (score 1):

1. you cannot open a javascript in a new tab.
2. You could use `onclick="return redirectPost...."` and add `return false`  to the end of your function or `event.preventdefault()` to the beginning, but that still would not allow you to use right mouse to open in new tab
3. BUT Just change your link to a submit button and submit the form as usual with the setting of the hidden fields in the onsubmit

Comment: Also, `form.submit` will override the following of the link anyway, so there's no need for the `return` (although of course it's best).

Comment: preventDefault at the top would be best in case of error in the script